# Natbib in-text citation displays year in brackets

Tags: citing, natbib

When citing a paper I want output to be like this: 
Ryan [1999] OR
(Chen, Liu, and Ryan [2008],Cheng, Dhaliwal, and Neamtiu [2011]). In other words, I need year to be in brackets.

However what I get is:
Ryan (1999) OR 
(Chen, Liu, and Ryan 2008,Cheng, Dhaliwal, and Neamtiu 2011)

I'm specifically referring to in=text citation.

Here is my code:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, open={(},close={)},citesep={,},aysep=}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,calc}

\usepackage{bigcenter} % pour centrer les grands tableaux

\usepackage[FIGTOPCAP]{subfigure}
\subfigtopskip = 20pt
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}

%\usepackage{bigcenter}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 % prevents footnotes to be placed on two pages

\hyphenpenalty=5000 % Discourage hyphenation
\tolerance=1000


\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
  Something is written here \citep*{chen2008characteristics,    
   cheng2011asset}. \citet*{ryan2007financial} says something here.

   \newpage
    \onehalfspacing
      %\begin{singlespace}    

      \bibliographystyle{jf}
       \bibliography{Bib_comp}

     \end{document}
```

I played with \setcitestyle but I can only get the opening bracket, I can't get the closing bracket for year. Also, it does not look pretty. I think I need to play with my sty file but I can't figure out what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you replace the instructions

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, open={(},close={)},citesep={,},aysep=}
```

with

```
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{citesep={,},aysep={}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I need. Your suggestion changes the parentheses to brackets for all citations. I'm not trying to change that. I'm trying to surround year with brackets. Here is what I get if I follow your suggestion [Chen, Liu, and Ryan 2008, Cheng, Dhaliwal, and Neamtiu 2011]. What I need is (Chen, Liu, and Ryan [2008],
Cheng, Dhaliwal, and Neamtiu [2011]).

Comment: @Seda - It looks like you're mis-using the `\citep` instruction. Please change the citation command from `\citep*{chen2008characteristics,cheng2011asset}` to `(\citet*{chen2008characteristics,cheng2011asset})`.

Comment: OMG, this is brilliant. I spent an entire day to find a solution and can't believe I missed the obvious. Thank you so much!